# 03 Ford Escape V6 Oil/Coolant/check fuel cap lights

Tags: ford, oil, coolant, cel, escape

I just had my oil changed and had coolant put into my car a few days before Christmas. Also, bought a new fuel cap the same day. All of these lights are still on and I have no idea how to make them go off. I read the manual and couldn't find it. I could be missing it but it has me worried :/

Help?

Comment: What does the owner's manual state to do when this light comes on?

Answer (score 1):

The check engine lights need to be read and cleared if you haven't done it already. This can only be done with an OBD-II scanner. If you don't have one, take it to an Autozone or the like. They can do it for you and will usually do so for free.